# How do I change the icon for an application on the KDE panel?

Tags: icons, plasma, panel, kde5, plasma5

I use KDE 5 on Fedora 22.

I want to change the panel icon for an application I use (say, okular). I don't care about how the app icon appears elsewhere (e.g. in the menus) - whether that changes or not is fine. Now, I'm *not* root on this machine. How can I effect this change?

**Note:** I don't mean the "quick-launch" icon, which you would see when the application is not running, but the icon on each of the running instances' tabs.

Answer (score 9):

kmenuedit will allow you do it via GUI

see this other question/answer

https://askubuntu.com/questions/647121/how-do-i-set-custom-application-icons-in-kde

Answer (score 6):

Look in `~/.config` for a file named `plasm-org.kde.plasma.desktop-appletsrc`.

It will contain something like:

```
[Containments][25][Applets][35][Configuration][General]
applicationName=GNU Emacs 24
genericName=Text Editor
iconName=/usr/share/icons/hicolor/scalable/apps/partitionmanager.svg
url=file:///usr/share/applications/emacs24.desktop
```

Change the `IconName` parameter to whatever you want the icon to be.

Comment: Note that editing the file while in KDE session the behaviour can be tricky. I recommend to logout from KDE and edit the file in terminal (`Ctrl+Alt+F1`, login, edit...).